# Dynamic column structure

Tags: crystal-reports

I have 3 Columns in my database: COL1, COL2, and COL3. I want to put them in my report but dynamically, like:

```
IF i = 3 THEN COL3
ELSE IF i = 2 THEN COL2
ELSE IF i = 1 THEN COL1
```

So the structure depends on conditions. so it is possible to have something like the following?

```
stringvar test:= COL;
numbervar i = 3;
{test + toText(i)}
```

I want to catch the exception if the column structure gets changed in the future.

Comment: use it in a formula..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[That's not exactly something Crystal Reports is well equipped for](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23452873/Crystal-Reports-how-do-I-use-a-string-variable-as-a-field-name-in-a-formula.html). There's no good way to use a string to determine which field to grab without using an if-else structure.

However if `COL4` gets added in the future, you'd still have to go in and change the report so `numbervar` can be set to 4. There's no good way for Crystal to anticipate a column that may or may not be there.

So keeping that in mind, the if-else statement is the best way to determine which column to grab. Although to save a little time on copy-pasting, you could prepare future lines of code as comments and activate them when the time's appropriate:

```
IF i = 1 THEN {table.COL1}
ELSE IF i = 2 {table.COL2}
ELSE IF i = 3 {table.COL3}
\\ ELSE IF i = 4 {table.COL4}
\\ ELSE IF i = 5 {table.COL5}
\\ ...
```

Comment: that was my second idea to have it like this, if crystal does not support the other way

Comment: Yeah, you would think that would be a supported feature. Crystal has been around a long time, and needs to support a lot of legacy code. Good object orientation practices weren't so much of a concern at the time.

Answer (score 0):

just like this:

```
numbervar s:=0; 
if {Command_1.emp_number} = 1 then

     s =  3
else

    s = 4;
```

Hope it helps as your guide..